# Jsp page need not to be Displayed

Tags: java, jsp, ptc-windchill

I have a jsp page from which I'm calling a Java class. That class contains code for pdf generation.

Now when I click the button an empty jsp also displays along with the pdf. I wish that jsp page will not get open when I click the button. Only that pdf should be displayed.

This is my jsp page.I'm calling the class which uses Windchill API

```
<%@page import="wt.part.WTPart"%>
<%@page import="wt.fc.WTObject"%>
<%@page import="ext.gt.checkOut.New"%>
<%
    String part2="GT024";
    ext.gt.checkOut.New.pdf1(part2);
%>
```

Comment: It could be better to help by seeing jsp code.

Comment: @Alexey:I have added the code

Answer (score 1):

Try to add
`<%`
`response.setContentType("application/pdf");`
`response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=yourfilename.pdf");`
`%>`

Answer (score 1):

Got from Windchill Q&A site http://ezcollab.com/questions/93/how-to-stream-file-in-jsp

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");       
BufferedOutputStream bufferedoutputstream = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
```